# Intel Fortran 11.1 Long Compile Times For Sources with Over 140 Modules

Tags: module, compilation, fortran, intel-fortran

I don't have a good grasp as to how long is "too long" when compiling and linking FORTRAN executables with many modules, but it seems that Intel FORTRAN v11.1 for Linux seems to take about 1.5 hours to compile a single .f90 file that contains over 140 modules.

Providing more background information, I'm compiling using this exe in Eclipse Photran using the Intel build chain and the default compiler options.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone can answer the following:

1. Is it normal for a Intel FORTRAN to take a long time (over 1 hr) to build the .mod files and then link the files?
2. Am I not setting up the build order or taking advantage of compiler options to speed the process?
3. Do new versions of Intel Fortran solve this issue (if it is a common one)
4. Can another compiler like gfortran compile with many modules faster?

Thanks in advance to any FORTRAN Jedi's who respond!

Comment: You have the code, you should try first if what can help you, how can any other people try more, withou your code?

Comment: The first step would be to try to place the modules into separate files and try to compile them separately. It can make a difference.

Comment: Compiling [ABINIT](http://www.abinit.org/) with IPO (afaik, similar to putting everything together) took me around 2 hours. So I think, this is a realistic time.

Comment: Good suggestion @Vladimir. I actually am in the process of separating out the modules and creating libs of the modules that do not need to be compiled often, which will certainly save me time.  I guess I was just reaching out to see if anybody was familiar enough with the compiler that they are aware of any tips or similar experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating the monolithic .f90 file containing several modules into separate files for each module made a huge improvement in compile times (from hours to only several minutes at most).

I suppose this is pretty obvious but I wanted to provide the answer for completeness and to share what I would consider as a best practice.

Comment: Intel Fortran has made many improvements in module processing over the years. But best practice is to have each module in its own file. With a current Intel Fortran (18), you could also use Fortran 2008 submodules to further reduce build times (and compile cascades.)